# how to getting video duration from shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video

How to get video duration from shell!?
I have a directory with too many videos file.
I want to print duration of total of the file in directory.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a command that can do what you want directly. You can try installing [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), and with it you get `ffprobe`.

If you run:

```
ffprobe videofile.avi
```

you get all the data about it (including the duration). Since it's based on ffmpeg, it supports more-or-less all the popular codecs.

With this, you can write a script to parse and sum up all the durations.

ps: for some unknown reason, my version of ffmpeg outputs data to STDERR instead of STDOUT. Dont know if it's a bug or a feature.